# Is there a way to create a local method in a method to avoid duplicating code?

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java, and I am currently writing a program which will allow for storage of books (Fiction and textbooks). I have a class for textsbook (Fagbok), and one for fiction (Skjønnbok), and I have a class Books (Bok) which includes an ArrayList of above mentioned books. Included is a method which will check if said book is already in the list. My question is; is there any way to avoid rewriting the code in "else", to avoid duplication? Could I make the first if(sjekkBok......) a method to be used later in the same method?

```
public Boolean eksisterer(Bok sjekkBok){
    boolean funnet = false;
    for(Bok bok : bøker){
        if(sjekkBok instanceof Fagbok){
            if(sjekkBok.getTittel().equals(bok.getTittel())){
                funnet = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(sjekkBok instanceof Skjønnbok){
                if(sjekkBok.getTittel().equals(bok.getTittel())){
                    funnet = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return funnet;
}
```

Apologies if it is a dumb question. Couldn't find any answers online.

Comment: Why not just have `if (sjekkBok instanceof Fagbok || sjekkBok instanceof Skjønnbok)` instead of separate if statements?

Comment: you may pull out this code to a private method

Comment: If you implement `equals()` properly in your book class, you can just use `List.contains()` and don't need to write the list iteration code by yourself.

Comment: Khelwood, that was exactly what I needed for this method. I did try that, but I made the (incredibly) rookie mistake of only writing || instancef.....

Answer (score 0):

You may not create functions within functions. **

Create a private method in the class and call it wherever, if its repetitive code.

**Functions within functions is not allowed as in you may not write a complete function A with a function B, but keep in mind there is [functional programming in Java 8](https://dzone.com/articles/functional-programming-java-8) which kind of enables this.

Comment: This answer is okay as an advice for a Java newcomer, but formally wrong. You can define Command objects and lambda functions in functions.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak the answer is specific to this question. And yes functional programming is supported in java 8. (answer edited)

Answer (score 0):

Do you always compare books by their type and title? If so, implement the `equals` method in `Book`. Otherwise you might want to use a [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), which is basically a class that contains the comparing logic. You can have multiple of such comparator classes and switch them in your list container class later on.